# Loops and 'exists' in batch files

Tags: batch-file

I have a hard time understanding the following batch script:

```
@echo off
echo b>b.txt
for /f %%A in ('echo b.txt b.txt') do (
    echo %%A
    if not exist %%A (
        echo does not exist.
    ) else (
        echo %%A exist.
    )
)
```

In the beginning, I make sure that a file "b.txt" exists, and then I would expect the loop to output twice the name of this file, and that it exists. However, the actual output that I get is:

```
b.txt
does not exists
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: This exact code works for me - try running it with b.txt already created?

Comment: I tried, that does not change the outcome for me. Do you have any idea what could be the difference my setup that it does not work?

Comment: I tried it with Win7-x64 and also with XP and it works!

Comment: works on mine too... One note, if you want your loop to execute twice, output needs to be on separate lines (`for /f` takes only 1st token if not instructed otherwise), so you'd have to do `'echo b.txt ^& echo b.txt'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as suggestion you may try to assign file name to variable just to make sure you reference exactly same thing in both statements, like this:

```
set file=b.txt
echo b>%file%
for /f %%A in ('echo %file% ^& echo %file%') do (
    echo [%%A]
    if  not exist %%A (
        echo [%%A] does not exist.
    ) else (
        echo [%%A] exist.
    )
)
```

I also removed echo off so you would see expansion output, and put brackets around `%%A` to see it's boundary

Edit: some addtional troubleshooting:
I would probably start building the script up from command line, changing only **only one  thing at a time**  and see where it breaks.

`if b.txt exist echo Exists`

If it works then

`for /f %A in ('echo whatever') if  b.txt exist echo Exists`

and so on, up to

```
for /f %A in ('echo b.txt ^&echo b.txt') do (if exist %A (echo %A exists) else (echo not exists))
```

You could also use different for variant (although I cannot see how it could make a difference):

`for %A in (b.txt b.txt) do (if exist %A (echo %A Exists) else (echo not exists))`

Comment: Thank you, but this code is still not working for me. In the first iteration, I get `[b.txt] does not exist.` and in the second iteration `[b.txt] exists.`. This is true no matter how many times I execute the script, or wheter b.txt exists in advance. I run Windows 7 x64. Do you have any idea why I get this weird behavior, or what I could try to find out?

Comment: that's very strange... I cannot replicate it. Maybe you could change `echo` to `dir /b`? This way you will be sure that this file *is* available to your bat on first run.

Comment: Similar result, the script prints that the first file does not exists (even though it is clearly there), and all subsequent files exist. Why is the first iteration different?

Comment: @goldfish It should not be any different... I will edit answer to include some addtional info

Comment: Thanks for the additional examples: Everything works, except the full code. In particular, it works if I use "b.txt" directly (instead of a variable), the different for variant works (even with the variable) and a stand-alone if also works.

I'm puzzled, any ideas?

Comment: @goldfish Run batch with its output redirected to file eg. `myBat >result.txt` (**make sure there is no @echo off in your batch**) and inspect what is produced. It should be exactly same code produced for each loop iteration. It certainly is on my PC.

Comment: This is really stupid, but the problem was caused by ansicon (a tool to enable colors in the console for Windows).  Once uninstalled, everything works again as expected. I'm not sure why it does not work with ansicon, it is still supposed to work.. Thanks for your help, anyway!

Comment: @goldfish I would make above your own answer and then accept it so it has better visibility. You could also report it to ansicon author.

Answer (score 1):

An old post I know and for some reason the problem was caused by Ansicon? I get the same result as you first posted without that program and the correct explanation, if you want to get it to echo all words, is that it seems to be that you need to specify tokens since every word it echoes will be one token and without specifying the amount of tokens it will only echo the first token. Add this **"tokens=*"** to your FOR /F statement as below.

```
@echo off
echo b>b.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('echo b.txt b.txt') do (
    echo %%A
    if not exist %%A (
        echo does not exist.
    ) else (
        echo %%A exist.
    )
)
```

That will produce this:

```
echo b.txt b.txt
does not exist.
```

So it will never find a file named "b.txt b.txt" since that is what %%A will translate to.
But if the goal was to echo all words after echo AND check for the existence of b.txt then this will work

```
@echo off
echo b>b.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('echo b.txt b.txt') do (
    echo %%A %%B
    if not exist %%A (
        echo does not exist.
    ) else (
        echo %%A exist.
    )
)
```

Output I get from above is this:

```
b.txt b.txt
b.txt exist.
```

I´m not sure what the script was supposed to accomplish so maybe this didn´t help at all.